# Subscribing of LiveData results in null after trying to fetch object from Room database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I write an app Medicine Reminder, where the medicine entity is stored in database using Room API. Flow of the app looks so:

1) Activity that has DrawerLayout, so it consists of NavigationView for Drawer and LinearView for Toolbar and Fragment.

2) Fragment #1 (TopFragment - it's ListFragment) - there is two options. Click on the first item should navigate to second fragment - MedicineListFragment.

3) MedicineListFragment fetches all medicine from db and displays it using RecyclerView - it works.

4) Clicking on an item - on item of recycler view - should create an intent that creates new activity MedicineDetailsActivity. Medicine Id of selected item is passed to intent in RecylcerViewAdapter implementation.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MedicineRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Medicine item = medicines.get(position);

    holder.itemNameView.setText(item.getName());
    holder.itemDescriptionView.setText(item.getDescription());
    holder.itemContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MedicineDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MedicineDetailsActivity.EXTRA_MEDICINE, item.getId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

5) Next step should be displaying of medicine details, but subscribing of Observer from ViewModel returns null instead a single medicine. What is weird, if I debug and set breakpoint before calling of .observer method the medicine is returned!

```
public class MedicineViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private AppDatabase db;

public MedicineViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    createDb();
}

public LiveData<List<Medicine>> findAllBooks() {
    return db.medicineModel().findAllMedicine();
}

public LiveData<Medicine> findMedicineById(int id) {
    return db.medicineModel().findMedicineById(id);
}

private void createDb() {
    db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(this.getApplication());
    DatabaseInitializer.populateAsync(db);
}
```

}

And that's MedicineDetailsActivity

```
public class MedicineDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MEDICINE = "EXTRA_MEDICINE";
private MedicineViewModel medicineViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medicine_details);

    medicineViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MedicineViewModel.class);
    subscribeMedicine();
}

private void subscribeMedicine() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int medicineId = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_MEDICINE);

    medicineViewModel.findMedicineById(medicineId).observe(this, new Observer<Medicine>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@NonNull Medicine medicine) {
            showUI(medicine);
        }
    });
}

private void showUI(Medicine medicine) {
    TextView medicineName = findViewById(R.id.medicine_details_name);
    medicineName.setText(medicine.getName());
    TextView medicineDescription = findViewById(R.id.medicine_details_description);
    medicineDescription.setText(medicine.getDescription());
}
```

}

```
05-26 09:10:20.258 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
05-26 09:10:21.282 9482-9489/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: Debugger is active
05-26 09:10:21.460 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: Debugger has connected waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:21.661 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:21.863 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:22.064 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:22.265 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out:  waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:22.465 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:22.666 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out:waiting for debugger to settle...
05-26 09:10:22.866 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/System.out: debugger has settled (1492)
05-26 09:10:23.395 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.project.medicinereminder-1/lib/arm64
05-26 09:10:23.416 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-26 09:10:23.463 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
05-26 09:10:23.524 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-26 09:10:23.826 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
05-26 09:10:23.832 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
05-26 09:10:23.892 9482-9511/com.project.medicinereminder I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-26 09:10:23.902 9482-9511/com.project.medicinereminder W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
05-26 09:10:24.002 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
05-26 09:10:24.253 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=29KB
05-26 09:10:24.254 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=29KB Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
05-26 09:10:33.236 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/hwaps: JNI_OnLoad
05-26 09:10:33.559 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=51KB, data=56KB
05-26 09:10:33.560 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: After code cache collection, code=50KB, data=55KB Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
05-26 09:10:33.750 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: Compiler allocated 7MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init> (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
05-26 09:10:47.687 9482-9489/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
05-26 09:10:47.728 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=118KB
05-26 09:10:47.729 9482-9487/com.project.medicinereminder I/art: After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=92KB
05-26 09:10:47.783 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
05-26 09:10:49.733 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project.medicinereminder, PID: 9482
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.project.medicinereminder.database.Medicine.name' on a null object reference
    at com.project.medicinereminder.MedicineDetailsActivity.showUI(MedicineDetailsActivity.java:44)
    at com.project.medicinereminder.MedicineDetailsActivity.access$000(MedicineDetailsActivity.java:16)
    at com.project.medicinereminder.MedicineDetailsActivity$1.onChanged(MedicineDetailsActivity.java:37)
    at com.project.medicinereminder.MedicineDetailsActivity$1.onChanged(MedicineDetailsActivity.java:34)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:109)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:282)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:87)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
05-26 09:10:49.749 9482-9482/com.project.medicinereminder I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9482 SIG: 9
```

I can put of course Parcerable or Serializable to intent (I tried with the second one - it works) but I want to do this using the aforementioned way.
Please help!

Comment: are you sure you have valid `int medicineId` in your `MedicineDetailsActivity`?

Comment: OK, you're right, I had to something change just before posting. Now I set `medicineId` type to `String` (and type of methods that fetch `Medicine` object) and as I've written - if I set breakpoint just before calling `medicineViewModel.findMedicineById...` it works, the medicine is fetched but if the breakpoint while debugging is there not set I get `null`.

Comment: ti be honest i am not sure what you mean by `"if the breakpoint while debugging is there not set I get null"`

Comment: ok, in private method `subscribeMedicine` I set two breakpoints: first on line where is `int medicineId...` (now `String`) and second on line where the method `medicineViewModel.findMedicineById...` is called. If I debug the app, the medicine is fetched. If the second breakpoint is set only, I get null.

Comment: post the full `logcat` stacktrace then

Comment: ok, stacktrace is already posted

Comment: i think this `DatabaseInitializer.populateAsync(db)` is the source of your problem as it populates your database in async way? am i right (i dont see how it is implemented but the method name suggest that)?

Comment: Exactly, thank you for hint and patience. In AsyncTask before every populating of database, method that deleted all data from database was called. I removed that method from the other method that is responsible for populating and now everything works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. Thank you @pskink

Following tutorial about Room API (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#0) before adding data to `in memory database`, every time I've initialized `MedicineViewModel`, I populated the database with test data. But just before it, `delete` method on the database was executed.

Because of asynchronous operation the database was not populated yet when MedicineDetailsActivity was created.

After removing `delete` method from `populate` method where records of medicine were added, everything works properly.